The "feature constructor" widget in Orange Data Mining disappear
I saw in Orange data mining documentation the there is a widget that is called "feature constructor" but I don't see it in my application.
I uninstalled the application and install again the last version, but still cannot see it anywhere.
I couldn't find any information in the internet.
Does anyone have an idea?
Please help me, I'm new in Orange.
Thanks.

The widget "feature constructor" has been renamed to "Formula".
